# CakePHP: JQuery Datepicker doesnt show DB value

Tags: jquery, cakephp, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I try to implement [this example](https://nik.chankov.net/2011/07/16/setting-datepicker-with-jquery-in-cakephp-project/) in my CakePHP 3.6.14 application.

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.widget( "ui.dp", {
            _create: function() {
                var el = this.element.hide();
                this.options.altField = el;
                var input = this.input = $('<input>').insertBefore( el )
                input.focusout(function(){
                        if(input.val() == ''){
                            el.val('');
                        }
                    });
                input.datepicker(this.options)
                if(convertDate(el.val()) != null){
                    this.input.datepicker('setDate', convertDate(el.val()));
                }
            },
            destroy: function() {
                this.input.remove();
                this.element.show();
                $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call( this );
            }
    });

    var convertDate = function(date){
      if(typeof(date) != 'undefined' && date != null && date != ''){
        return new Date(date);
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } })( jQuery );
```

So in the `default.ctp` I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
           $( "input.datepicker" ).dp({
              dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
              altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
           }); 

        });
```

And in the `edit.ctp` I have this control:

```
echo $this->Form->control('created_date', ['class' => 'datepicker', 'type' => 'text', 'empty' => true]);
```

While it submits and stores correctly the date in the database, when I open the edit page again I see today's date and not the one from the database. The database value is : 2019-06-27 and if I change the `dateFormat` option to `yy-mm-dd` I still get today's date instead of the one saved in the db.

But in the generated html code I can see that the value is correct:

[image]

Comment: If you don't use the date picker, and you don't override the default date format in the form control, does the saved date show correctly?

Answer (score 1):

With that script you are supposed to use the `altFormat` in your form control, ie `dateFormat` is the *display* format, and `altFormat` is the *value* format, and that format should be a standard ISO format, as the script tries to convert the value into a `Date` object, so non ISO patterns can cause wrongly parsed dates, or they cannot be parsed at all, which is what is happening with your value, as the [**JavaScript `Date` parser**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) treats the first number as the month, not as the day.

If your app's default date string conversion format doesn't match the `altFormat`, then you'll have to take care of that manually, for example like this for an individual field:

```
$value = $this->Form->getSourceValue('created_date');
if ($value instanceof \DateTimeInterface) {
    $value = $value->format('Y-m-d');
}

echo $this->Form->control('created_date', [
    'class' => 'datepicker',
    'type' => 'text',
    'val' => $value
]);
```

Also note that `yy` means full year in the jQuery UI datepicker, ie `2019`, not `19`, which seems to be your app's default. If you want to use the latter, then you need to use a single `y` in the `dateFormat` pattern.